# What is the opposite/antonyms for 'acquisition form'?

Tags: word-usage, antonyms

The antonyms for acquisition is loss and the such like found on [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/acquisition).

However 'loss' and the such like do not catcher the full scope that need to be reflected in this context. It need to be able to encapsulate loss, sold, broken... The idea of an object/item go out of my ownership, rather than object/item coming into my ownership, which acquisition does a quite good job at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a business context the opposite to an acquisition would be a *[disposal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disposal)*, which can be used to describe items that are sold or otherwise got rid of.

I would expect a "disposal form" to be used to document items leaving a person or business's ownership, with a field to categorise whether it was donated, sold, lost, stolen, etc.

Comment: Within the context of the problem that make perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate antonym for acquisition in the business world is divestiture or divestment.  Similar to disposal but lacks the "associated with garbage" connotation that this word conjures.